# Azure interactive login possible in Python?

Tags: python, azure

I'm a single user and i want to login to the cloud as a user. Are there any support for this in Azure python SDK?

I've previously used the CLI and used "az login" but not I would like to see if its possible to achieve the same in a pure python format.

So I would like to login to Azure as a user with password and email to authenticate.

Comment: See [How to authenticate and authorize Python apps on Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/python/azure-sdk-authenticate)

Answer (score 0):

I tried for a pure python strategy, but I came up short. My working proof of concept invokes az commands from python. It works, but I imagine there's a better way of doing it

```
import os

# interactive
os.system("az login")

# verifying successful login
os.system("az keyvault secret show --name <KEY> --vault-name <VAULT_NAME> --query value")
```

one optimization is to replace the az login above with this command instead

```
os.system("az account list-locations --output none || az login")
```

which will skip interactive login if you're already authenticated

Answer (score 0):

In my application, I found this code to be convenient: It automatically defaults back to interactive browser if you are not logged in.

```
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential

credential = DefaultAzureCredential(exclude_interactive_browser_credential=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help, with username, password, and client/tenant ID

```
import os
from azure.mgmt.resource import SubscriptionClient
from azure.identity import UsernamePasswordCredential

# Retrieve the information necessary for the credentials, which are assumed to
# be in environment variables for the purpose of this example.
client_id = os.environ["AZURE_CLIENT_ID"]
tenant_id = os.environ["AZURE_TENANT_ID"]
username = os.environ["AZURE_USERNAME"]
password = os.environ["AZURE_PASSWORD"]

credential = UsernamePasswordCredential(client_id=client_id, tenant_id = tenant_id,
    username = username, password = password)

subscription_client = SubscriptionClient(credential)

subscription = next(subscription_client.subscriptions.list())
print(subscription.subscription_id)import os
from azure.mgmt.resource import SubscriptionClient
from azure.identity import UsernamePasswordCredential

# Retrieve the information necessary for the credentials, which are assumed to
# be in environment variables for the purpose of this example.
client_id = os.environ["AZURE_CLIENT_ID"]
tenant_id = os.environ["AZURE_TENANT_ID"]
username = os.environ["AZURE_USERNAME"]
password = os.environ["AZURE_PASSWORD"]

credential = UsernamePasswordCredential(client_id=client_id, tenant_id = tenant_id,
    username = username, password = password)

subscription_client = SubscriptionClient(credential)

subscription = next(subscription_client.subscriptions.list())
print(subscription.subscription_id)
```

[Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/python/azure-sdk-authenticate-user-credentials)